# Perform Outlook Advanced Search with Delphi

Tags: delphi, outlook

I'm trying to do advanced search in Outlook with Delphi.
I'm actually trying to make the code displayed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.advancedsearch to work in Delphi 10.2 and up.
Outlook (office) versions I have is 2019 and 2021.
A search is performed in both inbox and sent folders.
However I cannot make it work

```
Var
   Outlook, oNameSpace, Attachment, MySearch, MyTable, nextRow, rsts  : OLEVariant;
   Inbox :  OLEVariant;
   i, j, iNbMail, iNbAttach: Integer;
   Mail, EmailAddress, UnReadFlag,  SaveName, AParent : Variant;
   AMessageID, Scope, AFilter, AStr: String;
begin

     try
        //create Outlook OLE
        Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
     except
           Outlook := Null;
           //add error/exception handling code as desired
     end;

try


  oNameSpace := Outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI');

  AStr:='test';
  // Search in both inbox and sent folders (works)
  Scope := QuotedStr(Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).FolderPath)
    + ','  + QuotedStr(Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).FolderPath);

  
  // The IsInstantSearchEnabled condition doesn't seem to work
  If Outlook.Session.DefaultStore.IsInstantSearchEnabled Then
        AFilter := Char(34) + 'urn:schemas:httpmail:subject ' + Char(34) + ' ci_phrasematch '+    (AStr)
    Else
        AFilter := Char(34) + 'urn:schemas:httpmail:subject ' + Char(34) + ' like ' + (AStr);
   
   // Filter condition with like works
   AFilter := 'urn:schemas:httpmail:subject like ''%'  + AStr + '%''';
   m_SearchComplete:=False;

   MySearch := Outlook.AdvancedSearch(Scope, AFilter, True, 'MySearch');
   While m_SearchComplete <> True do
   begin
        If MySearch.Tag = 'MySearch' Then
        begin
            m_SearchComplete := True;
        End;
        Application.ProcessMessages;
   end;
   rsts := MySearch.Results;
   ShowMessage('Count=' + VarToStr(rsts.Count));

   Application.ProcessMessages;
   MyTable := MySearch.GetTable;
   ShowMessage('Count=' + VarToStr(MyTable.GetRowCount));
   While Not MyTable.EndOfTable do
   begin
        nextRow := MyTable.GetNextRow ;
        //ShowMessage(nextRow.Subject);  // doesn't work 
        ShowMessage ('Found');
   end;
```

My problems are the following:

1. I don't know who to use the Application.AfvancedSearchComplete event in Delphi.
   I created a loop which searches the AdvancedSearch.Tag in order to check if the search is   completed, that is Application.AfvancedSearchComplete event supposed to do. This code works sometimes and many times doesn't return any reaches. I put some message boxes and some sleep functions in order to may it work sometimes. I also tied with open and closed outlook.
2. I didn't manage to get the value of the columns of the search results e.g. the subject.

Can anyone please help me with these issues?

Best Regards,
Manolis Perrakis

Hi, after thorough search in many sites and posts and components I came up that the proper solution is to use the code displayed in [Outlook Object Model - Detecting if email has been sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507342/outlook-object-model-detecting-if-email-has-been-sent) in which it creates a wrapper  and
can override/replace an event of a MailItem with a custom procedure.
This code is excuted correctly in Delhi 10.2 and actually displays a message when an meil is sent which is actually great. (Many thanks to Sertac Akyuz)

I tried to alter the code in order to replace the procedure AdvancedSearchComplete which exists in the ApplicationEvents_10 dispinterface in outllok2010.pas
I also created the Outlook_TLB.pas for the outlook 2016 type library using tlibimp.exe from the code diplayed in https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/1281-importing-excel2016-type-library-into-delphi/.  AdvancedSearchComplete also exists in Outlook_TLB.pas.

My code is like this:

```
TForm1 = class(TForm, IDispatch)
...
 Var
    FCookie: Integer;
    FMailItem: OleVariant;
    FSearch: OleVariant;
    //procedure MailSent;
    procedure AdvancedSearchComplete (SearchObject:OLeVariant);


 protected
    function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; override;
    function Invoke(DispID: Integer; const IID: TGUID; LocaleID: Integer;
      Flags: Word; var Params; VarResult, ExcepInfo, ArgErr: Pointer): HResult;
      stdcall;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    Var
      m_SearchComplete : Boolean;
  end;

Const
   DIID_ApplicationEvents_10: TGUID = '{0006300E-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}';
   AdvSearchCompleteDispID = 64106;

function TForm1.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult;
begin
  {if IsEqualGUID(IID, DIID_ItemEvents) and GetInterface(IDispatch, Obj) then
    Result := S_OK
  else
    Result := inherited QueryInterface(IID, Obj);   }

  if IsEqualGUID(IID, DIID_ApplicationEvents_10) and GetInterface(IDispatch, Obj) then
    Result := S_OK
  else
    Result := inherited QueryInterface(IID, Obj);

end;

function TForm1.Invoke(DispID: Integer; const IID: TGUID; LocaleID: Integer;
  Flags: Word; var Params; VarResult, ExcepInfo, ArgErr: Pointer): HResult;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
  //if DispID = SendItemDispID then MailSent;
  if DispID = AdvSearchCompleteDispID Then   AdvancedSearchComplete (FSearch);

end;

procedure TForm1.cxButton8Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
   Outlook, oNameSpace,  MySearch, MyTable, nextRow, rsts  : OLEVariant;
   Scope, Scope1, AFilter, AStr, ATag: String;
   CPContainer: IConnectionPointContainer;
   ConnectionPoint: IConnectionPoint;
begin
     try
        Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
     except
          Outlook := Null;
     end;

try

  oNameSpace := Outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI');
  AStr:='test';
  Scope := QuotedStr(Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).FolderPath)
    + ','  + QuotedStr(Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).FolderPath);

   AFilter := 'urn:schemas:httpmail:subject like ''%'  + AStr + '%''';
   m_SearchComplete:=False;

  // I use a dummy creation of the FSearch variable in order to be used in the Supports condition
  Scope1 := QuotedStr( Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox).FolderPath);
  FSearch := Outlook.AdvancedSearch(Scope1, AFilter, False, 'xxx');


  // ** Problem it doesn't return true to supports condition for the FSearch variable 
  // which source be typeof a Search Object 
  if Supports(FSearch, IConnectionPointContainer, CPContainer) then begin
    CPContainer.FindConnectionPoint(DIID_ApplicationEvents, ConnectionPoint);
    if Assigned(ConnectionPoint) then
      ConnectionPoint.Advise(Self, FCookie);
    CPContainer := nil;
  end;

  FSearch := Outlook.AdvancedSearch(Scope, AFilter, True, 'MyAdvancedSearch');

  if Assigned(ConnectionPoint) then begin
    ConnectionPoint.Unadvise(FCookie);
    ConnectionPoint := nil;
  end;
```

I changed the DIID_ApplicationEvents to DIID_ApplicationEvents_10
and again the support condition returns false

Adding the interface section from Outlook2010 and Outlook_TLB

```
DIID_ApplicationEvents_10: TGUID = '{0006300E-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}';

// *********************************************************************//
// DispIntf:  ApplicationEvents_10
// Flags:     (4096) Dispatchable
// GUID:      {0006300E-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
// *********************************************************************//
  ApplicationEvents_10 = dispinterface
    ['{0006300E-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}']
    function ItemSend(const Item: IDispatch; var Cancel: WordBool): HResult; dispid 61442;
    function NewMail: HResult; dispid 61443;
    function Reminder(const Item: IDispatch): HResult; dispid 61444;
    function OptionsPagesAdd(const Pages: PropertyPages): HResult; dispid 61445;
    function Startup: HResult; dispid 61446;
    function Quit: HResult; dispid 61447;
    procedure AdvancedSearchComplete(const SearchObject: Search); dispid 64106;
    procedure AdvancedSearchStopped(const SearchObject: Search); dispid 64107;
    procedure MAPILogonComplete; dispid 64144;
  end;
```

So my main problem is why the Supports(FSearch, IConnectionPointContainer, CPContainer) doesn't return true. And also how these functions can be modified in order to work for 2 or more events e.g. for the Send and AdvancedSearchComplete events .
(Or is there a way to reach Sertac Akyuz and hopefully can and wants to help)

Update
The first problem is solved
if Supports(FSearch, IConnectionPointContainer, CPContainer) then

should be

if Supports(Outlook, IConnectionPointContainer, CPContainer) then

It should search if outlook object is supported and not the result object of the advancedSearch. Now it finds the connection point but it
doesnot fire the AdvancedSearchComplete event. I'm searching for this and will return to reply to myself.